# How to use “Let” Aggregate options in mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, let, mongo-go-driver

Trying to use mongo-go-driver `SetLet` in the aggregate options to pass user variables defined earlier in my function into my aggregation pipeline.

Trying to parse the [documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/mongo/options/aggregateoptions.go) for this…

`SetLet` asks for just an `interface{}` for the input parameter.

I’m using a correctly formatted pipeline aggregation using “$$variableName” where I’m hoping the `SetLet` will fill in.

I’ve tried passing in a `bson.M` and a `map[string]interface{}` but neither of these result in a successful pass through for me (aggregation returns no documents).

Has anyone successfully used `SetLet` in `mongo-go-driver` and has a working example of how to use it properly?

Basic code example:

```
package test

import (
    "context"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func test() {
    // I would connect to an actual mongo database and get an actual collection, but I won't for example
    var col mongo.Collection

    // the variable I want to set via "Let" in my pipeline
    externalId := "test"
    let := bson.M{"externalId": externalId}
    options := options.Aggregate().SetLet(let)

    // The pipeline aggregation, I want my external variable to take place of "$$externalId"
    aggregation := bson.A{bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"id", "$$externalId"}}}}}

    // Perform aggregation and store result (Result will be empty because no documents were returned, because $match did not work)
    cursor, _ := col.Aggregate(context.TODO(), aggregation, options)
    var result any
    cursor.All(context.TODO(), &result)
}
```

Comment: Edited the post to include a basic code example of how I have this set up. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. My usage of `SetLet` was correct. The problem was that it seems like I cannot use a user defined variable directly in my `$match` pipeline stage. I need to use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) in order to properly use my user var.

```
bson.D{
            {"$match",
                bson.D{
                    {"$expr",
                        bson.D{
                            {"$eq",
                                bson.A{
                                    "$id",
                                    "$$externalId",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler's answer is correct about the using of `$expr` operator. Here is the note from the official documentation for the `let` option:

> To filter results using a variable in a pipeline `$match` stage, you must access the variable within the `$expr` operator.

See [Use Variables in let](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#use-variables-in-let).

The use of `bson.D` results in ugly code. It's better to use `bson.M`:

```golang
aggregation := bson.A{
    bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "$expr": bson.M{
                "$eq": bson.A{"$id", "$$externalId"},
            },
        },
    },
}
```